# Problem With Pages Displaying

Tags: pages, migration, publish

I am having a problem with any page other than my uncles home page displaying. The site was recently migrated from one host to another. The pages all show in the WP backend and are all formatted and all the content is there but when I click on the menu links it goes to error 404. I created a test page to see what happened with a new page. It worked and displayed as a preview but after I published it the same thing happens, error 404. The site is www.andyvalvur.com and is hosted on GoDaddy and came from Inmotion Hosting.

Any ideas? I appreciate any and all help that you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

9 times out of 10, this is an issue with the .htaccess.

Try flushing the permalinks:

1. Log into your WordPress Dashboard
2. Navigate to Settings => Permalinks
3. Click the Save button (don't change anything, just click save)

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks so much!!!